# C: fork() dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

Please consider below code snippet:

```
struct TASKS {char  taskid[4];};

struct TASKS *taskArray;

int main()
{
 for(;;)
 {
    taskArray = (struct TASKS *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct TASKS));
    printf("\ntaskArray:[%d]\n",taskArray);fflush(stdout);
    strcpy(taskArray[1000].taskid,"7");
    printf("main:[%d]  : [%d][%s]\n",getpid(),taskArray,taskArray[1000].taskid);fflush(stdout);

    returnvalue = fork();

    if (returnvalue == 0)
    {
        printf("Child:[%d]  : [%d][%s]\n",getpid(),taskArray,taskArray[1000].taskid);fflush(stdout);
        free(taskArray);
        strcpy(taskArray[1000].taskid,"10");
        sleep(3);
        printf("Child:[%d]  : [%d][%s]\n",getpid(),taskArray,taskArray[1000].taskid);fflush(stdout);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (returnvalue != 0)
    {
        printf("Parent:[%d]  : [%d][%s]\n",getpid(),taskArray,taskArray[1000].taskid);fflush(stdout);
        sleep(6);
        printf("Parent:[%d]  : [%d][%s]\n",getpid(),taskArray,taskArray[1000].taskid);fflush(stdout);
        taskArray = (struct TASKS *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct TASKS));
        printf("Parent:[%d]  : [%d][%s]\n",getpid(),taskArray,taskArray[1000].taskid);fflush(stdout);
    }
  }

    exit(1);
}
```

**Output:**

- taskArray:[11489296]
- main:[21060]  : [11489296][7]
- Parent:[21060]  : [11489296][7]
- Child:[21061]  : [11489296][7]
- Child:[21061]  : [11489296][10]
- Parent:[21060]  : [11489296][7]
- Parent:[21060]  : [11489328][]

Please help me confirm/understand the points below

- That the pointer addresses are virtual hence both the child and parent have different values even if the address looks same.
- free() in child frees the memory allocated to the child and doesn't affect memory allocated to parent.
- In calloc I have allocated only 1 item however I am trying to use [1000] and it still works out because the memory even if not allocated to me is still present. However its risky and might cause core dump in future. Similarly in child I am using the memory after free() it and it still works.
- In the parent I have huge memory leaks as there is no free(). Please help understand the side effects of this memory leak if the program runs in loop for ever until someone kills the process. Also please advise what happens when the process is killed, does it free all that memory?

**EDIT:**

I understand that many behavior's are undefined and the code is not logically correct however it still works out and executes. The question is about trying to understand why the ill-formed, ill-logical code works out & why.

Comment: Technically, `printf("\ntaskArray:[%d]\n",taskArray);` is UB. No point in checking the rest unless you fix this (or these).

Comment: Regarding the third point, going out of bounds of allocated memory leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and if you have that then your whole program becomes *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What is UB? Sorry I am new to this environment. [Okay i got it.] But i still don't understand how its undefined behavior.

Comment: Basically, yes / yes / yes / yes.

Comment: @pOrinG you don;t print a pointer using `%d`, read the man pages. and the UB is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Too broad and perhaps off-topic. Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [fork system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)); read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Then **use the debugger** and use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @SouravGhosh okay i got your point. We need to print pointer with %p.

Comment: `taskArray = (struct TASKS *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct TASKS));` and then `strcpy(taskArray[1000].taskid,"7");`?  You allocate **one**, and then copy to the **1001th** element?  Undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I understand the behavior is undefined however it still works and my question is why does it work out ? If you see point 3, i have mentioned the same thing.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @pOrinG It's quite pointless to analyse "why" something that's undefined "works". It fails to fail in a matter that you notice, that's not the same thing as knowing that it works. It's not correct, it's a bug. It might not crash, but there's no guarantee that it should crash. The behavior is *undefined*, and must be avoided in working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember from the 'C' course that `fork` creates a new process by copying the virtual paging table so, that the child would see absolutely the same values as the parent (usually the pages will have the read-only protection). However as soon as you start writing in the child memory space, the physical mapping of the corresponding page entry would be updated to point to the new location and data would be copied over to the new location.

*That the pointer addresses are virtual hence both the child and parent have different values even if the address looks same.*

- the `virtual` addresses look the same though their physical mapping might be different and, yes the values will be different.

*free() in child frees the memory allocated to the child and doesn't affect memory allocated to parent.*

- yes, it does not affect the parent since it will be done in the child's virtual space and child's physical mapping of this space. Free only means to manipulate pointers in the memory. So, the contents of the freed nodes can still be mapped to the parent space (till you start overwriting it).

*In calloc I have allocated only 1 item however I am trying to use [1000] and it still works out because the memory even if not allocated to me is still present. However its risky and might cause core dump in future. Similarly in child I am using the memory after free() it and it still works.*

- **don't!!** You are just reading values from the memory which is not what you think it is, if even legal, or corrupting it by writing. No matter if it is a child or a parent.

*In the parent I have huge memory leaks as there is no free(). Please help understand the side effects of this memory leak if the program runs in loop for ever until someone kills the process. Also please advise what happens when the process is killed, does it free all that memory?*

- when a processed gets killed by any means or exits normally all memory it uses usually gets returned to the OS for reuse. At least in all generic OS I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have seen people talk about copy-on-write which the forked processes use. So from that the parent and child are actually pointing to the same location until I change something correct?  So I wanted to understand the interaction with free. When I free a pointer in the child does it free and return the space to the memory-allocator from both parent and child or the parent still retains the allocated memory?

Comment: Also i didn't understand this point: `Free only means to manipulate pointers in the memory. So, the contents of the freed nodes can still be mapped to the parent space (till you start overwriting it).`

Comment: @poring Malloc/free usually work by manipulating lists of free/busy memory chunks.

Comment: @pOrinG - When you call `free(x)` you are saying "I will not use the memory x anymore" and the memory manager makes a note of that. That's all. If you then use x anyway, you are on your own and *anything* can happen - including x still being there for a while.

Comment: @BoPersson Okay i got it. And the fact that i am able to free(x) in parent as well as child separately tells me that the memory is allocated because if you try to free something in a process which is not allocated to you it gives core_dump or if you free it twice it gives `double free or corruption` error. Correct ?

Comment: @Serge Okay i got it. The memory is always there its just that it has not been allocated/reserved by you. malloc just reserves it for your process so no1 will use it and free just puts it back on the market but if we have a pointer address we can continue using it although i get it that its incorrect to do so as it can cause corruption & core dump.

Comment: @pOrinG - When you do a `fork()` you get a copy of the running program and then you have two of everything. The OS can do some virtual  memory tricks and not copy all the physical RAM *immediately*, but that doesn't change how the programs work. For example, sharing code between several running programs is done all the time, and not specific to forking.

Comment: @BoPersson I got confused with the virtual memory trick of OS : copy-on-write for `fork()` calls which is mentioned everywhere. Whatever the OS does for performance etc the basic thing is that when you fork you get a separate copy of everything in child including pointer's, dynamically allocated memory etc and we don't need to think about other things.

Comment: @pOrinG you can always think that the child memory is just a **copy** of the parent memory. The `copy` keyword would actually explain everything which you see. Virtual pages tricks are just the OS ways to implement the copy in the most efficient way (performance and memory-usage wise) and are hidden from you. The real implementation is more complicated than I described and is platform  and execution mode dependent.

Comment: @Serge Got it. Thanks :)